# PHP - Joomla 3.4.1 redirect for urls that contain missing categories

Tags: joomla

I am using the redirect plugin that is included with Joomla 3.5.  It works for regular urls but when there is an older 'missing category' url it fails.

Short of adding my own rewrite rule is there a php code fix for this in index.php?

Comment: Can you show an example of the failing link?

Comment: sure: http://www.net4geeks.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=69&Itemid=13  I copied that directly from a redirect entry in the admin redirect global configuration.

Comment: So you have that in the source url and then something else in the destination url field?  Just want to be sure I understand so I can try to reproduce. I hate the fact that it looks for category at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening. Unlike the usual behavior of a no longer existing page, your page is hitting this:

```
if ($category == false)
{
    return JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('JGLOBAL_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'));
}

if ($parent == false)
{
    return JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('JGLOBAL_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'));
}
```

Which is basically a hard coded 404 found in `/libraries/legacy/view/category/`.

This is because of this weird aspect of the api where even though it says `com_content` it doesn't check for the article first, it checks for the category first. I think it's a bug in support of long deprecated url structures and should be fixed to encourage migration, but that's just me, the question is what can you do.

So what you want to do I think is to intercept  that before it happens and then allow the normal operation of the plugin.  How I would approach that really depends on how many of the urls with this structure you expect to have to support. If it is just a couple, you could hard code. IF it is a lot you could  do a plugin really early in the stack and have it update the request to the url that you want by modifying the `JInput` object.  You could possibly do that by copying and then adding to the redirect plugin or by making your own separate system plugin.  I haven't looked closely enough at the redirect plugin in recent years to know if you can just modify the error handling there but that would be the place to start.

For more help on plugins try [joomla.se].

Comment: That at least gives me a hint in the right direction.  It's not like the site gets a lot of traffic anyway.  Running a quick query on the redirect_links table I found 143 urls with this problem.  Of those, only 4 had over 100 hits.  If I can get an .htaccess redirect working properly, I might just hard code those 4.  Just have to look up how to do that again... been a while.